# Java cant write in a .txt

Tags: java, printing, combobox, text-files

hello i desperately need your help,well i have a jframe with a jcombobox and 3 textfields i want anything i write in the textfields and the choice i make in the combobox to be written in a .txt i tried so many things but nothing , the file is being created as Orders.txt  but remains blank :S this is my code i appreciate any help Thanks :)

```
public class addSalesMan extends JFrame {
    private JComboBox namesJComboBox;
    private JTextField text1;//gia to poso
    private JTextField text2;//thn perigrafh
    private JTextField text3;//kai to numero ths paragelias kai ola auta tha egrafontai sto Orders.txt
    private JButton okJbutton;
    private String names[] = {"Basilis Komnhnos", "Iwanna Papadhmhtriou"};
   public String amount,name,description,number;

    public addSalesMan() {
        super("Προσθήκη παραγγελιών");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());//dialegoume to flowlayout
//        TextFieldHandler handler = new TextFieldHandler(); writer.write(string);



            //ftiaxonoume to combobox gia tn epilogi tou onomatos
        namesJComboBox = new JComboBox(names);//orizmos JCOMBO BOX
        namesJComboBox.setMaximumRowCount(2);//na emfanizei 2 grammes
                     add(namesJComboBox);
             namesJComboBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            //xeirozome to simvan edw dhladh tn kataxwrisei ston fakelo         
           public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event) {
//prosdiorizoyme an eina epilegmeno to plaisio elegxou
                if (event.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {                 

                            name = (names[namesJComboBox.getSelectedIndex()]);

//                            writer.newLine();             
                 setVisible(true);
            }
                 }
        });   //telos touComboBOx


        //dimioutgw pediou keimenou me 10 sthles gia thn kathe epilogh kai veveonomaste oti tha mporoume na ta epe3ergasoume kanontas ta editable

        text1 = new JTextField("Amount",10);
add(text1);
        text2 = new JTextField("Description",10);
add(text2);
        text3 = new JTextField("Order Number",10);
add(text3);

        TextFieldHandler handler = new TextFieldHandler();
        text1.addActionListener(handler);
        text2.addActionListener(handler);
        text3.addActionListener(handler);

        //private eswterikh clash gia ton xeirismo twn events twn text
//button kataxwrisis
 okJbutton=new JButton("Καταχώρηση");
 add(okJbutton);
 ButtonHandler bhandler=new ButtonHandler();
 okJbutton.addActionListener(bhandler);

    Order order=new Order(name,amount,description,number);
      Order.addOrders(name,amount,description,number);

    }
    private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent bevent ){

             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(addSalesMan.this,String.format("Η Καταχωρηση ήταν επιτυχής",bevent.getActionCommand()));


        }
    }
       private class TextFieldHandler implements ActionListener {
            //epe3ergasia twn simvantwn me kathe enter t xrhsth

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                String amount,description,number;
                amount=text1.getText();
                description=text2.getText();
                number=text3.getText();
                text1.selectAll();
                text2.selectAll();
                text3.selectAll();

              }
      if(evt.getSource()==text1 && evt.getSource()==text2 && evt.getSource()==text3){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(addSalesMan.this,String.format("Η Καταχωρηση ήταν επιτυχής",evt.getActionCommand()));

           }
      }

//actionperformed telos
            //ean o xrhsths patisei enter sthn kathe epilogh antistixi kataxwrisi sto

            }


          public static void main(String args[]) {
       java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        new addSalesMan().setVisible(true);
            }
 });
      }
    }
```

The writers are in another class. Here is the relevant code:

```
public static void addOrders(String name,String amount,String description,String o_number){
    FileOutputStream fout;
    try {
        FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("Orders.txt");
        if(name!=null){
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
            out.write(name);
            out.write(amount);
            out.write(description);
            out.write(o_number);
            out.write("\t\n");
            out.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println ("Unable to write to file");
        System.exit(-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the code that writes to the txt file?

Comment: Class names usually start with a capital letter: "AddSalesMan".

Comment: Where is `addOrders` being called in the above code?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the main problem is that you are calling `Order.addOrders()` in your constructor.  Instead, you should call it when a user chooses to save it's selection.  I assume you would like this to happen when the user presses the button.  So the code should be added in the button's `ActionListener`.

What you might need to try is flushing and closing the writer when a user closes your frame.

Add the following to the constructor of your frame:

```
addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    }
});
```

The above code will flush and close the writer when a user closes the frame.

Your code is unclear, so I'm not sure where the `writer` variable is declared,  I'm just assuming it is a class level variable.

Also, you need to open your file in 'append' mode if you want to add lines to the file instead of overwriting it every time.  This can be achieved through the following:

```
new FileWriter(yourFilePath, true); // set append to true
```

Comment: thanks JJnguy my writers are in another class :) this is the cod

Comment: @JJnguy: You hear that? You're the fish! :-)

Comment: @Donal, I get it ...Cod, a fish..ha

Comment: @mazin, I asked where the `addOrders` method is called in the code above.

Comment: underOrder order=new Order(name,amount,description,number); @JJNguy

Comment: @mazin, shouldn't you be calling `addOrders(name,amount,description,number)` instead?

Comment: iam just erase t by mistake in the question

Comment: @mazin, could you please edit your question to add the correct code.  It is difficult to answer the question when you don't provide the correct code.

Comment: @mazin, thanks.  I added some more info to the top of my answer.

Comment: @JJnguy thanks so i will ''transfer'' the addOrders to my confirmation button and flush/close ? right ?
really thanks for your patience and help

Comment: thanks i will try it right now and i will reply with the results thanks

Comment: @JJnguy i have now my writers in the same class but i cant use the code that u gave me addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    }
});  the writer is not found i quess:/ and even without that i have a blank .txt

Comment: @mazin, you will need to have a variable called `writer` as a member of your class in order for it to work.

Comment: @JJnguy please cee the code below .. i cant do anything thanks